# Difference between running a program with and without mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I implemented a peer-to-peer connection in MPI using `MPI_Open_port` and `MPI_Comm_accept`. I run a server and a client program using

```
rafael@server1:~$ mpirun server
rafael@server2:~$ mpirun client
```

on different computers. I noticed that

```
rafael@server1:~$ ./server
rafael@server2:~$ ./client
```

also works just fine. Do you know if there is any difference between starting an MPI executable with and without `mpirun`?

Of course, I can't give additional parameters (e.g. `mpirun --mca btl self,openib`), and the rank of all processes is 0, which is all totally fine. But is there anything less obvious?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Running without `mpirun`/`mpiexec` is called "singleton `MPI_INIT`" and is part of the MPI recommendations for high quality implementations, found under §10.5.2 in the latest MPI standard document:

> A high-quality implementation will allow any process (including those not started with a "parallel application" mechanism) to become an MPI process by calling `MPI_INIT`. Such a process can then connect to other MPI processes using the `MPI_COMM_ACCEPT` and `MPI_COMM_CONNECT` routines, or spawn other MPI processes. MPI does not mandate this behavior, but strongly encourages it where technically feasible.
>
> If a process enters `MPI_INIT` and determines that no special steps were taken (i.e., it has not been given the information to form an `MPI_COMM_WORLD` with other processes) it succeeds and forms a singleton MPI program, that is, one in which `MPI_COMM_WORLD` has size 1.

Using `mpirun` in your case is the *"parallel application" mechanism*, mentioned in the standard text. It provides `MPI_INIT` with the information necessary to establish `MPI_COMM_WORLD` over all started processes. Without the information from `mpirun` processes can only run as singleton MPI instances and hence all of them have rank `0` (which is OK, since each `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is a separate one).